# how to find corner (x, y) opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, game-automation

I have a picture of a pool game where I want to get the marked points from the picture (ball pocket)
Meanwhile, the background of the images may be different
How to get the coordinates of the table?

Exactly like the image below the orange line:

[image]

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile('1.png',))

gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray,100,150,apertureSize = 3)
Canny = cv.Canny(img,200,200)
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/450,500,minLineLength=70, maxLineGap=70)


for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
cv.imshow('1', img)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: hook into the game process. if it's a browser game, the same idea applies. -- what can be gained by botting this game?

Comment: great question. if the game process is proprietary then how could the user hook in @ChristophRackwitz ?

Comment: @Mojtaba. Sorry for the late reply. You need to do `cv2.fitline` instead of `cv2.line`.   Are you using `cv2.VideoCapture`?

Comment: No, I do not use the video, the image is a screenshot